# Why do the webidl specifications for WebGL extensions have the [NoInterfaceObject] extended attribute

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions, webidl

The [specification for [NoInterfaceObject]](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#NoInterfaceObject) states that the attribute "should not be used in specifications unless required to specify the behavior of legacy APIs".

Is there something about the WebGL extensions that are somehow unspecifiable and legacy? By way of example, here is the webidl for [AngleInstancedArrays](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/master/components/script/dom/webidls/ANGLEInstancedArrays.webidl)

Comment: this question seems like it would be better asked.on the official mailing liist: https://khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/ or on the official github issues: https://github.com/khronosGroup/WebGL/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for the reason given in "gman"'s comment.